# Fix object to top of browser window when scrolling only when browser is wider than mobile breakpoint

Tags: jquery, facebook, html, fixed, floating

I'm looking to adopt this technique to create a floating/fixed nav header on a website im working on.

demo here: jsfiddle.net/cc48t/

HTML:

```
<div id="scroller">Some controls</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#scroller').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
    }
}
);
```

CSS:

```
body {
    height: 3000px;
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#scroller {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #CCC;
    height: 100px;
}
```

How would i get this effect to work only for browsers with a large width (desktop) and to display regularly for narrower mobile devices. Much like the Facebook top bar is only fixed until a certain width break point where it returns back to the top of the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Simply ask for the document width, and apply the effect accordingly or not …?

Comment: Thanks, are you able to demonstrate what additions to the script are needed to apply this? I'm not great with jquery and would really appreciate further guidance with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// First get the window Width, in other cases you may want to get the inner but in this case with the outer we're good
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

//Then set the value for large width desktop

var desktopW = 980;

//And wrap your scroll function inside an if statement

if (windowWidth >= desktopW) {
 // your function
 } ;
```